# Need with Help Invalid outside source error

Tags: vb6

I am trying to process information with a dead mans program. Every time I try to run it I get Compile error Invalid outside procedure. I've never messed with VB6 before. I've been searching for a solution but I only get help saying it needs to be in sub or something but the threads are closed and I haven't been able to get their solutions to work for me. **http://pastebin.com/vR7A7iN5**

I think the problem is in this specific section of the code but I am unsure how to place it into a sub or get it to work otherwise.

```
End Type

Dim recout As statrec

Open "\STAT\PP\QM1409\MGA013A\" For Random As #1 Len = 150

num.recs = LOF(1) / 150
Print num.recs

For Count = 1 To num.recs

  Get #1, Count, recout

   If recout.mga = "013" Then
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is quite unclear. Please read [Help Center: "How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center: How to create a Minimal, Complete and verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: we should not have to go elsewhere to see code which will expire in 6 days.  include it here.  Otherwise that code needs to be inside a function or sub as the error indicates.

Comment: Where did you copy this code from? It is VB syntax, but it is not from a VB6 program. Is this from some VBA method?

Comment: It's a .BAS file I was told to use and it opens with vb 6.0 so that is just what I have assumed it was.

Comment: It is valid VB6 code.  There were better file handing methods, but those would work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a big reach to assume this is the only incompatibility, but start by wrapping the code you're talking about now inside a method as Plutonix mentioned. That IS definitely an error. However I would not be surprised if there are more problems.

*Example:*

```
Public Sub GetStatRecs()
    Dim recout As statrec

    Open "\STAT\PP\QM1409\MGA013A\" For Random As #1 Len = 150

    num.recs = LOF(1) / 150
    Print num.recs

    For Count = 1 To num.recs
        Get #1, Count, recout
        ....
    Next Count

    ....

End Sub
```

Comment: That causes an error must have start up form or sub main and takes me to the project properties window. I have sub main set as the startup object and noting else is available.

Comment: Then you need a Sub Main() in your .bas module. I don't want to sound mean about this, but you really need to do some reading on VB. This is the basic stuff.

Comment: It was kinda thrown on me suddenly because the guy who did it died and didn't leave very good notes about anything he did. I got volunteered as the I.T guy with the most amount of free time. Programming just hasn't clicked with me yet.

Comment: change the sub's name from `GetStatRecs` to `Main` it doesnt look like it does anything but change a character in a field as save back to the same file.